# Question regarding iPhone SDK Setting Bundle

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Hey guys, I'm currently testing my app by adding the setting bundle into my program but the program I'm facing now is when I test my app on my device, I go to the Setting screen and I couldn't found the setting of my app. If I test it on the iPhone simulator then I can find the app's setting in setting menu.

May I know what happens? How can I see my app's setting on my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing and re-adding your app to the device?  Also do a "Clean All" before doing this.

Comment: Now I got it after re-adding and do cleaning.. Thanks for help :D

Comment: Birdkingz: Please mark the checkbox if this is answered so the question is effectively closed